# Cypress and Axe seem to ignore content security policy

Tags: accessibility, cypress, content-security-policy, axe

I'm using Cypress and Axe to test my website for accessibility but it appears to be ignoring the content security policy (CSP) I have set using a meta tag.

When I run the test I get the following on cy.checkA11y():

```
EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
```

However the target web page ([andrewhick.com](https://www.andrewhick.com))'s source code contains the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; ">
```

I tried googling the error, but can't find anyone else with a similar enough issue.

I also considered whether the issue was caching, but reopening Cypress (which I believe should clear the cache) didn't help and besides, [Cypress clears the cache automatically](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearlocalstorage.html).

It could be because the CSP is defined in a meta tag rather than on the server, but I don't believe that my hosting company allows access to the server.

[The failing test is stored here](https://github.com/andrewhick/andrewhick-test/blob/main/cypress/integration/navigate.spec.js#L43).

Also unhelpful is the fact that the issue is intermittent and the suite did work once. I tried adding, removing and re-adding 'unsafe-eval' but the test results didn't correspond to whether the CSP had been updated or not. And although I'm not confident in Javascript, the test doesn't seem to have any obvious syntax errors. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not familiar with cypress but i would guess it inserts it's scripts into the page in a similar fashion to a browser extension, which is not allowed to use `unsafe-eval`. **Simple fix - just remove the CSP meta tag during testing.** To be fair by the time you have `unsafe-eval` and `unsafe-inline` it is almost pointless to have a CSP anyway so it isn't like it will damage your site security. You can always put your CSP back after testing.

Comment: If you are trying to learn about site security headers I would recommend https://observatory.mozilla.org/ as that covers most of the required security headers. Also as you look to be trying to implement HSTS you need to register the site here: https://hstspreload.org/. **Be warned** if you don't know what you are doing then you can really break your site with HSTS so make sure you have all your redirects correct etc. as at the moment the site would fail. You also can't set HSTS using meta tags, you have to send a header for HSTS to work.

Comment: Hi @GrahamRitchie, removing the CSP meta tag works for me, many thanks! Good point about it being redundant in this case. I'll take on board what you've said about Observatory and HSTS. At this stage, I'm not too worried about security as the site does not deal with sensitive data. But if I can build in the correct redirects and add HSTS then hopefully I can boost my security score further.

Comment: glad it helped! Good luck with your project.